# Coset representatives of principal congruence subgroups $\Gamma_l$ of $SL(n,\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Consider the level $l$ principal congruence subgroup $\Gamma_l$ of the special linear group $SL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ defined as the kernel of the natural map $\phi : SL(n,\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow SL(n,\mathbb{Z}/l\mathbb{Z})$.

Then the cosets of $\Gamma_l$ partition $SL(n,\mathbb{Z})$.

### My questions are:

1. What is the index of $\Gamma_l$?
2. How to explicitly construct the cosets of $\Gamma_l$?

p.s. This question was asked at [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/235541/coset-representatives-of-principal-congruence-subgroups-gamma-m-of-sln-mat), but put on hold for some reason. So I think I may ask it again here.

Comment: I answered Question 1 in a comment to the mathoverflow post! For Question 2, just write down all of the elements of ${\rm SL}(n,{\mathbb Z}/(l))$ and interpret the matrix entries as ordinary integers. That will result in a set of coset representatives.

Comment: I was not able to understand your answer by then. Now your comment makes sense to me by referring to the answer by knsam. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints.**

1. Show that the canonical map $SL(n, \mathbf{Z}) \to SL(n, \mathbf{Z}/l\mathbf{Z})$ is surjective.
2. Using the first isomorphism theorem, the index of $\Gamma_l$ (traditionally called $\Gamma(l)$) is the order of the finite group $SL(n, \mathbf{Z}/l\mathbf{Z})$.
3. We compute the order of the group $GL(n, \mathbf{Z}/l\mathbf{Z})$ and realise the group $SL(n, \mathbf{Z}/l\mathbf{Z})$ as the kernel of the determinant map $\det: GL(n, \mathbf{Z}/l\mathbf{Z}) \to (\mathbf{Z}/l\mathbf{Z})^\ast$ (which is surjective).
4. The Chinese remainder theorem lifts to the isomorphism of groups 
   $$GL(n, \mathbf{Z}/l\mathbf{Z}) \overset{\sim}{\to} \prod_{p^\alpha \parallel l} GL(n, \mathbf{Z}/p^\alpha\mathbf{Z}).$$
5. For primes $p$, the order of the group $GL(n, \mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z})$ is quite easy to compute. Study the canonical surjection 
   $$GL(n, \mathbf{Z}/p^{\alpha+1}\mathbf{Z}) \to GL(n, \mathbf{Z}/p^\alpha\mathbf{Z})$$
   to find the order of $GL(n, \mathbf{Z}/p^{\alpha+1}\mathbf{Z})$. (Here, show first that the kernel is a $p$-group using binomial theorem.)

Here is an in-principle answer for coset representatives: the coset representatives for $\Gamma(l)$ in $SL(n, \mathbf{Z})$ is just given by lifts of elements in $SL(n, \mathbf{Z}/l\mathbf{Z})$. This answer is not as "satisfactory" or as "computable" in the case $n = 2$, where there is a rather explicit recipe.

> For n = 2, one can construct coset representatives for the principal congruence subgroup starting with ideas in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1288512/65341) answer of mine.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed instructions. Really helpful.