# How can I find all coset representatives for $\Gamma_0(2)$ in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, modular-forms

$\Gamma_0(2)=\Big\lbrace\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix} \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z}):c\equiv0 \ (mod \ 2) \Big\rbrace$

I know that |$SL_2(\mathbb{Z}):\Gamma_0(2)|=3 .$ Thererfore there are 3 cosets . Now for fixed $a\in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ I can consider  the  left coset $a\Gamma_0(2)$ . Now my problem  is how to find all these cosets .

Comment: The answer to this post seems to address your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1288478/modular-forms-find-a-set-of-representatives-for-the-cusps-of-gamma-04